# My sitemap is indexed but I don't see the site pages being indexed

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console

Hi I have a site and my site map is being indexed by google correctly (almost I have 1.165 links and it indexed 1.156).

But when I go to the Indexed pages view in Google webmaster tools it only show 60 indexed pages and also I am not getting a lot of keywords because of that.

How can I improve that ?

My site is a single page Ajax filled app and I create a sitemap so google can find my content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get more links to your pages particularly the ones that aren't indexed yet.

Google does not automatically index every page it knows about and that includes URLs submitted via sitemap. Sitemaps are meant to inform the search engines of the existence of pages but in no way guarantees inclusion in a search engine's index.